# Is a vector space a quadruple or is it a set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

Is a vector space a quadruple or is it a set?

For example, I have heard statements like "$\mathbb R$ is a vector space." Does this mean $(\mathbb R,\mathbb R, +,\cdot)$ is a vectors space? (I saw some definitions say it is a quadruple, but it seems to be just a triple because a different field means a different scalar multiplication)

Or, does it mean $\mathbb R$ is a set such that it is possible to find two operations and a field such that the axioms are satisfied? So that any set that for which you can define two operations and find a field such that the axioms are satisfied is a vectors space? And a vector space over a field is one that you can find two operations together with that field that satisfy the axioms? So that any set that can be a vector space over at least one field is a vector space?

I often see statements like $f:V\to W$. If vector spaces are just sets, then that makes sense. But if vector spaces are not sets, do $V$ and $W$ mean the corresponding sets in the quadruples? And, statesment like $V$ is a vector space over $F$ and W is a vector space over $G$, when combined with the above function definition, are confusing. It seems like $f$ accepts only vectors, do fields make a difference on $f$?

Comment: This is a relatively nuanced distinction you are making and is part of a more general idea of differing between a set and what is commonly known as a "set with structure" (or a space sometimes). Some more examples are groups, rings and topological spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Formally, a vector space is nonempty set of Vectors that is associated with some field $K$  with defined operations addition and scalar multiplication.

Informally, when there is a 'default' set of operations and fields, we will be lazy and call the whole structure by just the set of vectors

Comment: I'd restrict myself in the formal discussion calling vector space as a set of vectors..., because then we must define a vector as an element of a vector space which makes this discussion circular.

Comment: By "associated", do you mean a vector space is the combination of the set of vetors, the field, and the operations, so that it is a set of two sets and two operations? And, how to distinguish between two vectors spaces with the same vectors but different fields and operations?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it's the second option. A vactor space is always a quadruple. When one says that R is  vector space it's short for what one associates with R as the "usuall" vector space, over the field R and the "normal" addition and multiplication.